# What is digital twin/device shadow?

Tags: azure

I am confused with the terminology used with digital representation of physical device. Correct me if I am wrong. I understand, Digital twin as it is the JSON doc which is stored in one of file based data base and store information about the current config, required config and policies. But I am not sure is it the same?

Please help me to understand what actually is digital twin and how we can implement it.

Thanks for the help!

Reference I am using: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/about-digital-twins

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Although I want to use digital twin or device twin to maintain the device state.

Comment: Okay I got you. But I have explained my understanding above and if my understanding is correct. Then I wanted one solution to build this concept. I better need to rephrase my question. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

A digital twin is just a (virtual) object that entirely reflects the state of the physical device.

This means that any time the device changes state it needs to report this back to the "cloud". If the change is triggered from the cloud this is not a problem because the digital twin can be updated as the request is acknowledged.

But if the device has say a physical button that can change state, these updates also need to be sent up to the "cloud".

The point of the digital twin is to allow any system wanting to interact with the device to know its current state without having to query it first as the digital twin should always be up to date.

There are many ways to implement it, but they are normally backed by database of some sort to allow for failure recovery or load balancing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please share one of the way to implement.

Comment: The in memory database. Okay I don't want to bother you. But it would be very thankful if you can be more illustrative or can share one of the repo from where I can look and understand.